# Oracle Report Migration Chr(13) display Square

Tags: oracle, oraclereports

The Oracle report from 11g migrated to 12c,
the chr(13) in the data are all show in square. Any one can help.
Thank you so so much.

[Square Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4LZf.png)

Answer (score 0):

Replace it with `CHR(10)`, e.g.

```
select replace(column_name, chr(13), chr(10))
from ...
```

Comment: I know I can replace only using chr(10) is okay, but any support/ reference from Oracle that they cannot support the chr(13) in oracle report 12c?  Since 11g is okay.

Comment: Have a look at My Oracle Support and/or contact them; I wouldn't know why they (Oracle corp.) did it that way.